# unknown outcome for a date column in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to add a column to an existing Pandas dataframe, but some of the values don't make sense (or at least are in an unknown format). I want to get either the end date of a certain stage based on the start date of the next stage, or I want the end date to be equal to the start date if the proces has ended, or if the proces is still ongoing the date of 'today'.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta, date

my_list = [[1, '5-6-2019', 1, 4], [1, '15-7-2019', 2, 4], [1, '20-10-2019', 3, 4], [1, '26-10-2019', 4, 4], [2, '5-6-2019', 1, 5], [2, '15-7-2019', 2, 5], [2, '20-10-2019', 3, 5], [2, '26-10-2019', 5, 5], [3, '3-6-2020', 1, 1], [4, '6-6-2020', 1, 1], [5, '7-6-2020', 1, 3], [5, '7-7-2020', 2, 3], [5, '31-7-2020', 3, 3], [6, '10-7-2020', 1, 2], [6, '13-6-2020', 2, 2], [7, '18-6-2020', 1, 2], [7, '21-7-2020', 2, 2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['ID', 'Start_date', 'Stage_ID', 'Max_stage'])

df['Start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])
today = date.today()


conditions = [
    (df['Stage_ID'] == 1) & (df['Max_stage'] > 1),
    (df['Stage_ID'] == 2) & (df['Max_stage'] > 2),
    (df['Stage_ID'] == 3) & (df['Max_stage'] > 3),
    (df['Stage_ID'] == 4) | (df['Stage_ID'] == 5)]

solutions = [
    (df['Start_date'] - timedelta(days=1)).shift(-1),
    (df['Start_date'] - timedelta(days=1)).shift(-1),
    (df['Start_date'] - timedelta(days=1)).shift(-1),
    df['Start_date']]   

df['End_date'] = np.select(conditions, solutions, default=today)
df
```

So if the stage is 1, 2 or 3 and that is not the last stage, then the end date is the start date of the next stage minus one day (hence the minus timedelta(days=1) and the shift(-1)). If stage is 4 or 5, the process has ended and hence the end date of that stage is the same as the start date. In all other case the process has not ended the date of today is included (hence default=today).

The outcome of my code is:

```
    ID  Start_date  Stage_ID    Max_stage   End_date             
0   1   2019-05-06  1           4           1563062400000000000  
1   1   2019-07-15  2           4           1571443200000000000
2   1   2019-10-20  3           4           1571961600000000000
3   1   2019-10-26  4           4           1572048000000000000
4   2   2019-05-06  1           5           1563062400000000000
5   2   2019-07-15  2           5           1571443200000000000
6   2   2019-10-20  3           5           1571961600000000000
7   2   2019-10-26  5           5           1572048000000000000
8   3   2020-03-06  1           1           2020-09-30
9   4   2020-06-06  1           1           2020-09-30
10  5   2020-07-06  1           3           1593993600000000000
11  5   2020-07-07  2           3           1596067200000000000
12  5   2020-07-31  3           3           2020-09-30
13  6   2020-10-07  1           2           1591920000000000000
14  6   2020-06-13  2           2           2020-09-30
15  7   2020-06-18  1           2           1595203200000000000
16  7   2020-07-21  2           2           2020-09-30
```

The End_date that I expected are:

```
    ID  Start_date  Stage_ID    Max_stage   End_date             
0   1   2019-05-06  1           4           2019-07-14 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
1   1   2019-07-15  2           4           2019-10-19 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
2   1   2019-10-20  3           4           2019-10-25 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
3   1   2019-10-26  4           4           2019-10-26 (stage is 4, so start date=end date)
4   2   2019-05-06  1           5           2019-07-14 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
5   2   2019-07-15  2           5           2019-10-19 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
6   2   2019-10-20  3           5           2019-10-25 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
7   2   2019-10-26  5           5           2019-10-26 (stage is 5, so start date=end date)
8   3   2020-03-06  1           1           2020-09-30 (no condition is met, so default = today)
9   4   2020-06-06  1           1           2020-09-30 (no condition is met, so default = today)
10  5   2020-07-06  1           3           2020-07-06 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
11  5   2020-07-07  2           3           2020-07-30 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
12  5   2020-07-31  3           3           2020-09-30 (no condition is met, so default = today)
13  6   2020-10-07  1           2           2020-06-12 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
14  6   2020-06-13  2           2           2020-09-30 (no condition is met, so default = today)
15  7   2020-06-18  1           2           2020-07-20 (= start date of next row minus 1 day)
16  7   2020-07-21  2           2           2020-09-30 (no condition is met, so default = today)
```

So, only the date of 'today' is right. The other 'dates' have a weird outcome/format. Is this some sort of absolute number that I can convert to a date (somewhat like in Excel). Or is my code wrong. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following experiment: I replaced

```
df['Start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])
```

with

```
df['Start_date'] = df['Start_date'].apply(lambda s:
                                          date(int(s.split('-')[2]),
                                               int(s.split('-')[1]),
                                               int(s.split('-')[0])))
```

so that you actually only deal with `date` objects. The output looks better. But I'm not sure if it produces the intended results? I looks a bit different from what you get.

Results:

```
    ID  Start_date  Stage_ID  Max_stage    End_date
0    1  2019-06-05         1          4  2019-07-14
1    1  2019-07-15         2          4  2019-10-19
2    1  2019-10-20         3          4  2019-10-25
3    1  2019-10-26         4          4  2019-10-26
4    2  2019-06-05         1          5  2019-07-14
5    2  2019-07-15         2          5  2019-10-19
6    2  2019-10-20         3          5  2019-10-25
7    2  2019-10-26         5          5  2019-10-26
8    3  2020-06-03         1          1  2020-09-30
9    4  2020-06-06         1          1  2020-09-30
10   5  2020-06-07         1          3  2020-07-06
11   5  2020-07-07         2          3  2020-07-30
12   5  2020-07-31         3          3  2020-09-30
13   6  2020-07-10         1          2  2020-06-12
14   6  2020-06-13         2          2  2020-09-30
15   7  2020-06-18         1          2  2020-07-20
16   7  2020-07-21         2          2  2020-09-30
```

**EDIT**: There's also some odd odd stuff going on in your code: `5-6-2019` becomes `2019-05-06` (which seems wrong) while `21-7-2020` becomes `2020-07-21`? You can fix that by using an explicit format string `pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')`.

**EDIT 2**:
If you take the odd number `1595203200000000000` and look at:

```
print(date.fromtimestamp(1595203200))
```

you get `2020-07-20` which seems to be the intended result. So, the right result is there, it's just the format that isn't right.

Comment: Thanks Timus, I will look into your answer. I'll come back to it.

Comment: I get exactly the same with your piece of code included in mine and the result I expected. So this works perfectly. I still wonder what happened in the first place... If I add a column without all the conditions (so something like this: df['End_date'] = (df['Start_date'] - timedelta(days=1)).shift(-1)), I get a date in the right format. And the same for the other two (df['End_date'] = df['Start_date']] or df['End_date'] = today). But with the np.select function and the conditions it goes wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce your last EDIT comment. 5-6-2019 becomes 2019-06-05 in my code (which is right) and 21-7-2020 becomes 2020-07-21...

Comment: @Frank0013 The list from which you construct the frame starts with `'5-6-2019'` but the first `Start_date` in your question is `2019-05-06`.  Or did I miss something?

Comment: I see it now. I'm very sorry, this is a typo. I did strip my actual df to get the above example. I must have made a mistake. Thanks again for your help tonight!